# inline xaml in html document

Tags: html, xaml

How could I view XAML code inside html document, this is my XAML code:

```
<Canvas Name="myxaml"
        Width="618.125"
        Height="37.325001"
        ClipToBounds="True"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Canvas Name="g10"
            RenderTransform="1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,37.325001">
        <Canvas Name="g12">
            <Path Fill="#FF000000"
                  Name="path16">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero"
                                  Figures="M41.977,17.434L41.977,18.165 48.719,18.165 48.719,17.434 41.977,17.434z M41.977,15.165L41.977,15.891 48.719,15.891 48.719,15.165 41.977,15.165z" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

and my goal is doing something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span>
      <Canvas Name="myxaml" Width="618.125" Height...............</canvas>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

And if it isn't possible, is it possible to convert xaml to html, I found a tool called [html2xaml](http://html2xaml.codeplex.com/releases/view/51179) it converts from html to xaml and visversa but it results in no output for such xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try saving the xaml as a file, and opening them in a vector based illustration editor such as InkScape, and then export to a more html friendly format (such as SVG, which could be displayed inside the canvas).

Link : 
[Inkscape supports XAML](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/01/08/inkscape-svg-xaml-conversion-scale.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually my target browser is IE8, so I couldn't use svg, but I tried to convert xaml to html5 using inkscape but with now luck